# Grub2 datehook.mod secureboot on

Tags: grub2, module

datehook.mod provides variables such as $HOUR, $DAY - we use these to control the boot options. This module is not included in the signed grub binary, so when Secure Boot is enabled on the PC, our custom grub config no longer works. How run/include datahook.mod when secure boot is on?

Comment: you said that it is not included ... how do you expect to run something that does not exist?

Comment: Cross-posted on [askubuntu.com/questions/1342469](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1342469). Please don't cross-post questions, see [meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068).

Comment: Im ask how add or run this module if possible.